# How to sort date and display in uitableview header

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my NSMutableArray(xmlParseArray) date are comes from server and the data is

2010-05-14
friday 10june,2010
this is test app
this is first application
means in xmlParseArray 10 records are coming, i want to show these records according date(sorted date) wise and date on tableview header with format friday 10 june, 2010 format
how can i achieve this. any help is appreciated .
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an NSMutableArray of objects with a field "beginDate" of type NSDate you can use an NSSortDescriptor as below:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"beginDate" ascending:TRUE];
[myMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];
```